# Can't create a new event template from an existing event template

Tags: civievent, templates

in Civi 4.5.4 I'm trying to create a new event template from an existing template.
When I do that, I start at this screen:
/civicrm/event/add?action=add&is_template=1&reset=1

When I select an existing template, functionality is expected - the page is populated with the details from the existing template. The page's URL stays the same.

However, when I click continue, I suddenly get transferred to an event creation page. The URL changes to: /civicrm/event/manage/location?action=update&reset=1&id=128  (ID being the eventID)

A new event (of ID 128) has been created and there's no sign of a new event template.

Is this a bug that's been fixed somewhere that I haven't been able to find, or am I missing something here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you might want to try using the latest version of 4.5, i.e. 4.5.8 and see if the bug is still present in that version. An upgrade should be relatively easy between minor releases

Comment: I am having the same problem with CiviCRM 4.6.6.  The steps are as follows: go to Event Templates, click on Add Event Template, choose an existing template in the From Template field.  This copies over the existing template as expected but when you click save it saves it as an Event not an Event Template.

Comment: Actually, cloning an event template seems to be exactly what was intended. When you choose New Event Template, the "From Template" has this help: "You can select an existing Event Template as the basis for the new template you are creating, or you can create the template from scratch". The same problem is still happening in 4.7.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think cloning an event template was planned as a feature. I think event templates were meant to be used for creating new events.

So the above behavior is probably doing what was designed.

Comment: Ahh, that's very helpful advice. Thanks so much!

Comment: It would be a useful feature if it were properly implemented.  However, if cloning a template isn't possible then the 'From Template' field should be removed from the event template creation form.  Currently it makes for a confusing user experience.  You think you are creating a new template but end up creating an event.

Comment: I disagree with @donald-lobo. Its not doing what it says, which is clearly offering a template from a template. It still behaves incorrectly in 4.7.27 which I am on and will check in the latest version on the demo site when I have a moment. It would be quite reasonable not to offer the feature, but it would be useful. So it should either be removed or corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at the demo site http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org (CiviCRM 5.4.alpha1)and tried it there and it looks like it was a bug that is now fixed so all you is upgrade to CiviCRM 4.7.31 or later).

See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21743 for details of the bug/fix.